# How to wait for http requests to finish when using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

get value from input from specific page using fetch API

but the problem is, when I fetch the HTML file the input value is empty because javascript file from the HTML fills the input and it takes some time. Is there any way to wait for http requests to finish so I can get value from it?

```
fetch('some.html').then(res => res.text())
  .then(res => {
    let parser = new DOMParser()
    let htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(res, 'text/html')
    console.log(htmlDoc.querySelector('#mobile2').value)
})
```

Comment: `DOMParser` is synchronous, hence the log line waits for the parser getting finished its job. Rather the script in the parsed document fragment is not executed. See the specs: https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-domparser-interface "_script elements get marked unexecutable_"

Answer (score -4):

just add `setTimeout`

```
fetch('some.html').then(res => res.text())
  .then(res => {
    // wait for 1 second
    setTimeout(() => {
      let parser = new DOMParser()
      let htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(res, 'text/html')
      console.log(htmlDoc.querySelector('#mobile2'))
    }, 1000)
})
```